# call localhost web services --> connection refused

Tags: java, linux, web-services, wsdl

I have the problem. Let me describe the situation first.
I have setup the weblogic cluster in two machines on linux OS.
I have deployed the web application and web services on them.
In the web application, it will call "http://localhost:7201/BusinessLogic/services/AccountService?wsdl" web service. But it said connection refused in the log.
But if I change localhost to be ip address of one weblogic machine IP, it is working. e.g. "http://192.168.0.30:7201/BusinessLogic/services/AccountService?wsdl" where 192.168.0.30 is one of ip address of web application machine.

I have checked /etc/hosts, it has mapping 127.0.0.1 localhost.

I checked in my computer to use postman to call web service "http://192.168.0.30:7201/BusinessLogic/services/AccountService?wsdl", it is working. Of course, I cannot test localhost in my computer.
I also think is there a way to check localhost web service on linux machine. is there a way??

Where is the problem??

Please help!!!

Comment: Do you have a listen address configured in WebLogic? In the admin console navigate to Environment -> Servers -> Server -> Configuration -> General.

Comment: Usually, web server applications will listen to `0.0.0.0`, which means every local IP address, including the `127.0.0.1` loopback address, and your `192.168.0.30` IP address. If the application has been told to only listen to `192.168.0.30`, then it will not be listening to `127.0.0.1`, which is why it doesn't see the request against `localhost`.